# Need help printing a list vertically

Tags: python, list

I'm very new to Python, and coming here was a last resort. I have spent hours poring over my notes and the internet to try and figure out how to do this, to no avail.

I have a list that is organized similar to this one:

```
classes = ['''Thermodynamics, MSE345, Smith, Quantum Mechanics, MSE350, Johnson, Electrical Engineering, ECE322, Roberts, etc. etc.''']
```

I need to print out the list vertically with the class, course code, and professor on one line like so:

> Thermodynamics, MSE345, Smith
>
> Quantum Mechanics, MSE350, Johnson

Since the list has commas separating the class, code, and professor, I can't figure out how to print the list with all of those things on one line together.

when I entered the code --> `classes.split(',')`, it printed each comma separated phrase on it's own line, and they are contained in ' '. I need to get rid of the quotes and brackets. If you could help me out with this, I would be very appreciative. Not looking for someone to do my homework for me, if you could explain the commands I need to use I can (hopefully) figure out the rest on my own. This is my first week of programming, I feel this is a little over my head!

Comment: Why does your list have one big string in it instead of one string per logical item?

Comment: msw, please do not insert whitespace into a multi-line string literal.

Comment: point taken, I realized that was doubleplusungood just before you rolled it back; sorry

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't say this is the best way to do it, but if it is your first week of programming it might be the easiest to understand

```
classes = "Thermodynamics, MSE345, Smith, Quantum Mechanics, MSE350, Johnson, Electrical Engineering, ECE322, Roberts"
classes = classes.split(',') #turn it into a list
for i in range(0, len(classes), 3): #every third index
    print classes[i] + ',' + classes[i+1] + ',' + classes[i+2] #print 3 elements with commas
```

Output

```
Thermodynamics, MSE345, Smith
Quantum Mechanics, MSE350, Johnson
Electrical Engineering, ECE322, Roberts
```

Comment: +1 for doing it with the tools likely at OP's disposal. CS101 would likely discourage the use of `itertools` for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

First, what you want to do is to `split` your long string of classes into a list, you can do that by using `str.split(',')`. Then you can iterate over this list in chunks of three to form pairs of class data. For this you can use `itertools` (specifically `groupby`) [documentation here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

classes = "Thermodynamics, MSE345, Smith, 
    Quantum Mechanics, MSE350, Johnson,
    Electrical Engineering, ECE322, Roberts,
    etc. etc."

classes_list = classes.split(",")

for i in grouper(classes_list,3): # or even grouper(classes.split(",")...)
    print str("".join(i)) # formatting fix
```

Output:

```
 Thermodynamics MSE345 Smith
 Quantum Mechanics MSE350 Johnson
 Electrical Engineering ECE322 Roberts
...
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of using a list with just one item make it into a string that looks like this:

```
classes = 'Thermodynamics, MSE345, Smith, Quantum Mechanics, MSE350, Johnson, Electrical Engineering, ECE322, Roberts, etc. etc.'
```

then use `split(',')` to make a list of each item separated by commas then separate the list into list of lists that are 3 items long like so

```
class_list = classes.split(",")

sorted_list = [class_list[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(class_list), 3)]

print sorted_list
```

this will print

```
[['Thermodynamics', ' MSE345', ' Smith'], [' Quantum Mechanics', ' MSE350', ' Johnson'], [' Electrical Engineering', ' ECE322', ' Roberts']]
```

Answer (score 1):

My best advice would be for you to use a dictionary instead of a list or at least a list inside a dictionary containing all the other values for a given key

Answer (score 1):

Hmm if I just think of the simplest solution possible...

```
for i in range(len(classes))//3:
    j = i * 3
    print(', '.join(classes[j:j+3]))
```

Something like that should work. This is assuming that every element in your list is some string...and that the list has a length that is a multiple of 3 and you want to print in groups of three, line by line, separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

1. len (classes) is 1. "classes" is a single string.
2. As a result, you might as well consider solutions where classes =
   ''' .... ''' (or foo = classes [0], and solutions that operate on
   foo.
3. When you do that, you need to worry about the string spanning
   multiple lines. The ''' construct allows for the trailing ''' to occur many lines later. But if preceded and ended by parentheses you have one line. With out the parentheses, you have one long string of multiple lines.
4. Gotcha - The name of a class or the instructor might have a comma
   '''C, C#, C++, and similar languages, CS203, Kernighan, Richie, et.
   al, editors, .....'''
5. Even if in the Gotcha case, you can use the course ids as
   "separators", you need to worry about the instructors being
   separated from the course name. Yuck

Answer (score 0):

```
def group(classlist, n):
    l = len(classlist)
    for inc in xrange(0, l, n):
        if (inc + n) < l:
            yield tuple(classlist[P] for P in xrange(inc, inc+n))

classes = ['''Thermodynamics, MSE345, Smith, Quantum Mechanics, MSE350, Johnson, Electrical Engineering, ECE322, Roberts, etc. etc.'''][0].split(',')

newlist = [ person for person in group(classes, 3) ]

print newlist
```

Output:

```
[('Thermodynamics', ' MSE345', ' Smith'),
(' Quantum Mechanics', ' MSE350', ' Johnson'), 
(' Electrical Engineering', ' ECE322', ' Roberts')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another method:

```
In [28]: s = "Thermodynamics, MSE345, Smith, Quantum Mechanics, MSE350, Johnson, Electrical Engineering, ECE322, Roberts"

In [29]: splits = s.split(', ')

In [30]: n = len(splits)

In [31]: zip(*[splits[i::3] for i in range(n / 3)])
Out[31]:
[('Thermodynamics', 'MSE345', 'Smith'),
 ('Quantum Mechanics', 'MSE350', 'Johnson'),
 ('Electrical Engineering', 'ECE322', 'Roberts')]
```